# Trying to reinstall steam but snap wont let me

Tags: snap, steam

I'm trying to remove steam from my computer because I installed it through snap and it was giving me problems, and I cant remove steam because I get the error "error: snap "steam" has "remove-snap" change in progress" I aborted the process in terminal by doing "snap changes" and "sudo snap abort 13", and I tried to remove steam again, but it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 4):

So, you installed steam through the snap store and when you tried to remove it, the process froze and then the snap cannot be removed.

The problem, as stated [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/automatic-snapshots-snap-remove-purge-proposal/11294), is that by default on snap remove, snapd creates a snapshot of the data and keeps it around for 31 days. Some snaps are slow to remove as they create lots of data (ex. 2GB+ of data). In the case of steam it gives the following error:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Save data of snap "steam" in automatic snapshot set #2 (tar failed: context canceled)
```

--

1. First (although you already did) lets check that there are no more processes pending. This will show you the processes performed and their status. In terminal type:

```
snap changes
```

2. If there is any process pending, abort it:

```
sudo snap abort <ID number>
```

3. Reboot the system:

```
sudo reboot
```

4. Check in terminal snap changes again. All processes should be completed.
5. Now, to avoid the problem with the automatic snapshot generated error - when removing the snap, disable it. In terminal type:

```
snap set core snapshots.automatic.retention=no
```

6. Finally, you can remove the snap (and reinstalled if you like, but as recomendation, better use the apt package):

```
sudo snap remove steam
```

Comment: where do I set this? snapshots.automatic.retention=no

Comment: the command must be typed in terminal as stated, what it does is disable the automatic snapshot generator.

Comment: Maybe better to use `snap remove --purge steam` to avoid creation of a snapshot instead of disabling automatic snapshots for all snaps.